# Why does JMS acknowledge mode not work in wildly with ibm mq?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to use acknowledge mode in delivering messages from ibm queue via JMS.

So, I configure context in this way:

```
 private JMSContext createJmsContext() throws JMSException {
        JmsConnectionFactory cf;
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, props.getProperty(Q_HOST));
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty(Q_PORT)));
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, props.getProperty(Q_CHANNEL));
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, props.getProperty(Q_MANAGER));
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.ACKNOWLEDGE_MODE, WMQConstants.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return cf.createContext();
    }
```

Here is special parameter:

```
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.ACKNOWLEDGE_MODE, WMQConstants.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

In code logic I use message listener which processes messages:

```
consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {

            try {
                // business logic
                message.acknowledge();
            } catch (Throwable e) {

                try {
                    // saving unsuccessful message to special database
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // if database does not work, we want message to return back to queue and try process it again when database will work
                    sleep(60_000); // to prevent too many process requests, there is only one working thread, so we can pause it
                }

            }

        });
```

Now this code does not work: if database fails, message will be lost. We can not find it via JMS browsing. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using sessionMode parameter when creating context. As far as I know a context created without specifying `sessionMode` is same as `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` where JMS client will automatically acknowledge message after it is delivered to application. So for your case you will need to use:

```
cf.createContext(JMSContext.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

I tried and it works for me, meaning if `message.acknowlege()` is not called, the same message is delivered again.

Comment: Yeah, it works, and also context.recover() is required to start receiving messages from last unacknowledged one